# The exit code, the return echo is different from the exit code of the program. Why?

Tags: bash, unix, exec, solaris, exit-code

I wrote a program that returns an error code using processes.
The result of the work of the program, if at the entrance to it provide the command of a false, is 255.
However the command
false; echo $?
returns 1
Why it happens?
Solaris, unix

I found the file false.c in the source code, it returns 255 (not sure if this is the right command) 
https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/blob/master/usr/src/cmd/false/false.c

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <wait.h>

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int status;
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid == -1){
                perror("fork error");
                exit(-1);
        }
        if (pid == 0) {
                execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);
                perror(argv[1]);
                exit(-5);
        }
        if( wait(&status) == -1){
                perror("wait");
                exit(-1);
        }
        if(WIFEXITED(status))
                printf("exit status: %d\n",WEXITSTATUS(status));

        exit(0);
}
```

Comment: *Which* `false` are you executing? bash has a builtin false. Consider bash's `command` and `builtin` commands.

Comment: Why don't you show the relevant part of your program instead of the source code of a third-party program you are not even sure belongs to the binary you are calling. Also, try to find out which false it is you are calling (use `type false` and your package manager).

Comment: If you run `false` in bash, it'll use the bash builtin. If you run `false` via `exec*p` then it'll run the system's binary.

Answer (score 0):

UNIX (Linux, Solaris, BSD, etc.) exit codes may only be 0 - 255, where 0 is good and non-zero is an error. Exit codes are not signed, so the -1 may be converted to another (non-zero) value, as are values over 255.

Comment: *UNIX (Linux, Solaris, BSD, etc.) exit codes may only be 0 - 255* That's no longer true.  [Per POSIX 7](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/signal.h.html): "The exit value in `si_status` shall be equal to the full exit value (that is, the value passed to `_exit()`, `_Exit()`, or `exit()`, or returned from `main()`); it shall not be limited to the least significant eight bits of the value." AFAIK Linux is still not compliant with this part of the POSIX standard. But `WEXITSTATUS` still only returns the lowest 8 bits.